# Fields for password1, password2 show up(at registration page) even after using "exclude" variable in Meta class of UserRegistrationForm in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-registration

At the registration page of a Django web app, I want to just ask for desired username and the email address and the system will email a randomly generated password to the user's given id. What should I do with this?

I am using django 2.2.2 & python 3.7.3. I am using crispy_forms to render the forms.

Relevant django forms documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).

I have already used the "exclude" variable in the Meta class of my UserRegisterForm class. See code for exactly what I have done

In `forms.py` file:

```py
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    Inheriting the UserCreationForm class to add some additional fields in
    the registration form because the #s of fields
    in the UserCreationForm class has less fields than required.
    We add email field in this extended class.
    """

    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")
        exclude = ("password1", "password2")
```

My `register.html` template file:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend>
          Join here!
        </legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div>
        <button>Sign up!</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <small class="text-muted">
      Already have an account? Sign in <a href="{% url "login" %}" class="ml-2">here</a>.
    </small>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

my `views.py` file:

```py
def register(request):
    """
    Triggered when AnonymousUser clicks on the 'Sign Up' button anywhere on the site

    The process:
    1. User visits registration page
    2. User enters his/her email only.
    3. System makes an account in the database & sends an email
       to that id with the password.
    4. User logs in the website using that password
    """
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            request.POST = request.POST.copy() # To make the request.POST mutable
            request.POST['password1'] = get_random_alphanumeric_password(_max_len=8)
            request.POST['password2'] = request.POST['password1']
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                # WORKS!
                messages.success(request, _(f"Account successfully created"))
                send_mail(subject=_(f"KBank - Password for {request.POST['username']}"),
                          message=_(f"Thanks for signing up at KBank. The password is {request.POST['password1']}"),
                          from_email=os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER"),
                          recipient_list=[f"{request.POST['email']}"],
                          )
                messages.info(request, _("Please check your email for password & log in using that"))
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        return render(request, "users/register.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        return redirect("site-home")
```

The error is two fields asking for password1 & password 2 still show up on my registration page.

[image]

Comment: Lol, I removed the `fields` option and the form showed the fields asking for "What permissions do you like?"
I tried removing the `exclude` from it but to no avail

Comment: Please show your view. Are you sure you're using your overridden form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman added the relevant view function to the question

Answer (score 0):

The `fields` and `exclude` attributes are for fields created from the model. The password1 and password2 fields are not from the model, they are extra fields defined directly on UserCreationForm.

You could override the init method to delete those from the form, but I'm not sure why you would do this. And I also don't understand why, if you don't want to show the forms, you still want to mutate request.POST to pass them in. Really you should just use a standard ModelForm, then set the random password on save. So:

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")

def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                new_password = get_random_alphanumeric_password(_max_len=8)
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, _(f"Account successfully created"))
                send_mail(subject=_(f"KBank - Password for {user.username}"),
                      message=_(f"Thanks for signing up at KBank. The password is {new_password}"),
                      from_email=os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER"),
                      recipient_list=[user.email],
                )
        ...
```

(Note, you should be using the data from the user object, not the raw POST data, in the email.)

Comment: I got your point. To clarify, I only want the registering user to enter his email & a username so that I can send a randomly generated password to his email. And that's why I need not show the fields asking password & password confirmation.

Comment: And I was modifying the request.POST content because a) I forgot that I can modify the way you told me b) I still was receiving the password1 & password2 parameters in my post so I thought of modifying them. My bad. Sorry for all this fuss.